# Primefaces Editor not working in IOS device browsers (Chrome/Safari)

Tags: ios, jsf, primefaces, editor

I have a responsive web application which is used across Ios/Android/Desktop, The Editor from Primefaces does not seems to work in Chorme/Safari on IOS Mobile devices (Ipad/Iphone), Trying to debug it I found out that it shows the source (the text that is displayed when the 'show source' button is clicked). [Editor Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgUby.png)